# Resolving TypeError when comparing unicode strings in conditional

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two classes that are connected by a FK constraint in the model.  After executing a query, I'm packing a list of the return objects in the `QuerySet` where the related object's field matches the equality comparison.

```
tagList = ContractPlanTags.objects.filter(tag_value_id = "44") | ContractPlanTags.objects.filter(tag_value_id = "45")

tagCollection = []

for tag in tagList:
  if tag.tag_value_id.tag == u"SNPFlag" | tag.tag_value_id.tag == u"PlanType":
    tagCollection.append(tag)
```

For reference, `tag_value_id` is a FK reference to another object which contains the `tag` field.  As a result of the if comparison, I'm getting

```
ERROR: test_metaobject_access (app.tests.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jason/workspace-sts/rowdmap_taxonomy/app/tests.py", line 58, in test_metaobject_access

if tag.tag_value_id.tag == u"SNPFlag" | tag.tag_value_id.tag == u"PlanType":
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wanted a [boolean `or` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) instead:

```
if tag.tag_value_id.tag == u"SNPFlag" or tag.tag_value_id.tag == u"PlanType":
```

or, for this specific case, you could also use an `in` membership test:

```
if tag.tag_value_id.tag in {u"SNPFlag", u"PlanType"}:
```

You cannot use the [`|` bitwise OR operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) on unicode strings; it usually applies to integers instead:

```
>>> 10 | 1
11
```

or to sets (see all [supported set operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)):

```
>>> {1, 2} | {2, 3}
set([1, 2, 3])
```

or on objects that define the [`__or__` special method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__), such as what the Django-specific `.filter()` method returns.